# Connection Timeout for mongodb using mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a web application running on Node, express and MongoDB. I use mongoose as the ODM. When i tested my application with mongodb version v3.0.1 it runs fine and throws no errors. But when i run the same code v3.2.10 i get a connection timeout after some time.

I get the following Error :

```
Error: connection timeout at null.<anonymous> (/webapp/node_module/mongoose/lib/drivers/node-mongodb-native/connection.js:186:17)
```

I use mongoose.connect for the db connection to the local mongodb instance.
Has anything changed in the way of connection ?

Comment: the connection timeout at 'null' makes me suspect the proper port number isn't being passed to mongoose's connection.js module - have you considered this?

Comment: it connects fine runs fine for some time. So i think the connection works fine but this error comes up after 20-30 mins.

Comment: @Dan I have the same issue. If you could solve it, let me know how.

Comment: did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: For more information please visit to: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html#options

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I had this problem a while ago. It all depends on which version of `mongoose` and `mongodb-core` you are using. Right now, you have to specify the following parameters:

```js
mongoose.connect("mongodb://user:password@address/db", {
  server: {
    socketOptions: {
      socketTimeoutMS: 0,
      connectionTimeout: 0
    }
  }
});
```

However, just yesterday, the correct parameters where

```js
mongoose.connect("mongodb://user:password@address/db", {
  server: {
    socketOptions: {
      socketTimeoutMS: 0,
      connectTimeoutMS: 0
    }
  }
});
```

I don't really know what to believe in anymore..

Comment: Also see this: https://github.com/christkv/mongodb-core/issues/153 There is an issue when setting the timeout in the latest mongodb-core  .

Answer (score 8):

I realize that this is an old question, but the accepted answer now contains deprecated code. To set a connection timeout with Mongoose v5+, you now need to put all of the options at the top level of the options object, not nested like before:

```
mongoose.connect(uri, {
  useUnifiedTopology: true, // For Mongoose 5 only. Remove for Mongoose 6+
  serverSelectionTimeoutMS: 1000, // Defaults to 30000 (30 seconds)
})
```

Comment: Is 1000 enough to prevent timeouts? Is there any side effect if I set it to 30.000? @Mike

Comment: @GökhanPolat That depends on what you're trying to do. Set it to whatever you want the timeout to be. I just used 1000 as an example.

Comment: `socketTimeoutMS` is independent of `useUnifiedTopology`. It is not a deprecated/defunct option.

Comment: @ZachB It's been a while since I wrote this answer, but I believe [this](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/5.x/docs/connections.html#v5-changes) is what I was referring to. Now, options are declared at the top level, not nested.

Comment: @ZachB I've edited the answer for clarification.