# Mongo query is throwing a timeout on big db

Tags: javascript, angular, mongodb, mongoose

I'm new to mongo and angular, and I just solved an issue with one local mongo db and I'm able to execute a query on a small db; now I'm trying to query on a big db 210GB but every time I execute my query I got a timeout even if I filter by 1 record.

Is there something I'm missing?

This is the query I'm using

```
let q = 'ClientID : 18481';

await Activities.find({q}, function(err, users){
            if (err) throw err;
            // object of all the users
            console.log(users);
        }, 20000);
```

Also this is my Protractor conf related to jasmine

```
  jasmineNodeOpts: {
    showColors: true,
    defaultTimeoutInterval: 300000,
    allScriptsTimeout: 300000,
    isVerbose: true
  },
```

and Here is the output I got

````
Failures:
1) dashboard_links update time frame filter to Today
  Message:
    Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.
  Stack:
    Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.
        at listOnTimeout (timers.js:327:15)
        at processTimers (timers.js:271:5)
  Message:
    MongoNetworkError: connection 0 to server.qa.test.online:27017 timed out
  Stack:
    MongoNetworkError: connection 0 to server.qa.test.online:27017 timed out
        at Socket.<anonymous> (/Users/moisessiles/Automation/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/connection.js:259:7)
        at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:285:13)
        at Socket.emit (events.js:197:13)
        at Socket._onTimeout (net.js:447:8)
        at listOnTimeout (timers.js:327:15)
        at processTimers (timers.js:271:5)
  Message:
    Failed: connection 1 to server.qa.test.online:27017 timed out
  Stack:
    MongoNetworkError: connection 1 to server.qa.test.online:27017 timed out
        at Socket.<anonymous> (/Users/moisessiles/Automation/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/connection.js:259:7)
        at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:285:13)
        at Socket.emit (events.js:197:13)
        at Socket._onTimeout (net.js:447:8)
        at listOnTimeout (timers.js:327:15)
        at processTimers (timers.js:271:5)
    From: Task: Run it("update time frame filter to Today") in control flow
        at UserContext.<anonymous> (/Users/moisessiles/Automation/node_modules/jasminewd2/index.js:94:19)
        at /Users/moisessiles/Automation/node_modules/jasminewd2/index.js:64:48
        at ControlFlow.emit (/Users/moisessiles/Automation/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/events.js:62:21)
        at ControlFlow.shutdown_ (/Users/moisessiles/Automation/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:2674:10)
        at shutdownTask_.MicroTask (/Users/moisessiles/Automation/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:2599:53)
        at MicroTask.asyncRun (/Users/moisessiles/Automation/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:2728:9)
        at /Users/moisessiles/Automation/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:668:7
        at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/next_tick.js:81:5)
    From asynchronous test: ```
````

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40585705/connection-timeout-for-mongodb-using-mongoose

Answer (score 1):

Your actual problem is that the query takes that long. Looking at your query:

```
 { q:  'ClientID : 18481' }
```

do you really need to have a string with a name inside a field `q` ? Couldn't you just structure your objects as:

```
 { clientID: 18481 }
```

then you are querying on a number instead, which is way faster, and it keeps your database clean. With that you can also easily create an [index](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#indexes) for that field:

```
Activities.index({ clientID: 1 })
```

that will turn your *search* into a *lookup*.

> 210GB

How did you achieve such a big amount of data? Try to structure your data (as shown above), to reduce the size of the database by enabling mongodb to store it more elegantly.

Also keep in mind that databases have to store a lot of data in the RAM to run fast, if your server cannot handle this amount you might want to [shard](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/sharding/) your data across multiple servers.

If all that doesn't help to decrease the loading time under the timeout, you could [increase / disable the timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40585705/connection-timeout-for-mongodb-using-mongoose).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, so I'm new to mongo and angular, and I'm not follow you on remove the quotes from my query. I also tried limit just 1, 2 but didn't get success on the results. About the amount of data, this is a client DB, I just need to use the data that they provide me.

Comment: @msiles could you provide some sample data of the db?

Comment: I think we can close this, I was using some of the index on the existing collection and I'm getting results.